# What to do when an OP posts someone's email address?

Tags: discussion, personal-data

I just came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34988404/did-capitals-ever-matter-in-email-addresses) (which has since been deleted) asking whether capitalization matters in email addresses. In this question the user states this:

> This morning I am doing a testing on our website and database. I saw
>   this in our database email field "[an possibly real email address]"

Now, I can't tell if this email address is modified or not, but it could be that the OP just posted someone's email address publicly on the internet, without his knowledge.

What do I do in this case?
I can modify the post, obfuscating the email address, but it can still be found by search engines and what not in the revision history.

Comment: First, you hope that the person that asked this question doesn't work at a company you do business with, then I'd consider leaving a comment so it can get fixed in the grace period without any edit history, then I'd try to close it asap so that it can become a candidate for auto deletion. Its up to you if you feel it still needs editing out.

Comment: If someone's email were STAR.WARS@hotmail.com -- I'd expect them to already be on every spam list.

Comment: @Sayse the act of leaving a comment would interrupt the grace period.

Comment: @TZHX - Ah I wasn't aware of that

Comment: Just edit out/replace the email and flag for a mod, requesting that a Stack Exchange developer goes in and wipes the original revision from the database.

Comment: Just delete the question. It's not a programming one anyway. Wasting developer time for it seems a waste.

Comment: @TZHX feel free to start a close vote. I don't have the required rep yet.

Comment: @Ivar it's already closed as duplicate. Would require diamond to delete it at the moment I think, or X number of 20k-users?

Comment: @TZHX: As it's at -3 and closed, 3+clamp(0, 7, (qscore+max(ascore, 0))/20) 20K-s can delete it. Which is incidentally the minimum of 3 at the moment.

Comment: When you do see users carelessly leaking PII if you can identify the jurisdiction you could report it to the appropriate regulatory authority for that region. A lot of countries have a body with a remit for prosecution/fines of negligence in data handling.

Comment: Meh. Email addresses aren't that private. Mine's all over the web, Gmail does a great job of spam filtering.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

1. Edit the email to end in `@example.com` ([or `.org`, `.net`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606#section-3) if one of those is more appropriate).  It's worth doing this immediately, since it will at least defeat the dumb scrapers that don't understand edit history.  That's hardly all of them and may not even be most of them, but it is a nonempty set (there are a lot of dumb scrapers out there).
2. Flag it for mod attention and explain the situation.
3. If you have close or delete votes, consider using them (based on the question as a whole, not just because it used an email address).

If you don't have 2k rep, you can probably skip (1) since mod flags are likely handled faster than edit reviews anyway.

It hardly matters, though.  Almost every email address that an actual person uses will inevitably end up on a bunch of spam lists sooner or later (e.g. mailing lists, shady companies that ask for your email, friends who don't secure their own computers, etc. can all potentially expose your email in ways largely beyond your control).  Avoiding the public posting of real addresses is desirable, of course (which is why you should do something about it, instead of just ignoring the problem), but it isn't nearly as effective as high-quality spam filtering.

Comment: `since mod flags are likely handled faster than edit reviews anyway.` - for a custom flag, it can take hours or days for a mod to get to it.  But the edit review queue is usually cleared within minutes (at least on Stack Overflow).

Comment: What happen once mods have been pinged? Can they edit the history to remove the email address from the first version of the post?

Comment: @AL mods cannot edit history, but developers can.

Comment: ... which makes me wonder, how do moderators bring something up for intervention from an SE employee.

Comment: @DanNeely we go ask 'em to do it for us

Comment: The fact that email is associated with a particular website has been leaked, not just the fact that the email is legitimate. Depending on the website and the person, this breach of privacy could be serious.